# Hibernate deletion issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, transactions

I'm trying to write a Java app that imports a data file. The process is as follows

1. Create Transaction
2. Delete all rows from datatable
3. Load data file into datatable
4. Commit OR  Rollback if any errors were encountered.

The data loaded in step 3 is mostly the same as the data deleted in step3.

The deletion is performed using the following

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(myObject.class);
List<myObject> myObjects = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
hibernateTemplate.deleteAll(myObjects);
```

When I then load the datafile, i get the following exception

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: 
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
```

The whole process needs to take place in transaction.
And I don't really want to have to compare the import file / data table and then perform an insert/update/delete to get them into sync.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest answer, use [session.merge()](http://www.hibernate-training-guide.com/merge.html)

Short answer, use plain jdbc hibernate is the wrong tool for this job.

Longer answer, see what your database tools support in this regard.
A solution could be to:

1. rename table old_table
2. create an new empty table
3. import the data into the new table
4. drop old_table

Your entire table would be locked in your use case so this should not be a problem.

Comment: probably the simplest solution. Unfortunately the db account we're using only has update/insert/delete access.  I might have to go with a nsert/update/delete instead of a drop all... ta

Answer (score 0):

First idea: did you try to `flush()` the `Session` after step #2?

Second idea: use [the `StatelessSession` interface](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession). You may have to extend `HibernateTemplate` for that since [SPR-6202](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6202) and [SPR-2495](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-2495) are unresolved.